# Allen Brain Atlas in XTK?

Tags: xtk, neuroscience

How can I render the Allen Brain Atlas ([API documentation](http://help.brain-map.org/display/api/Downloading+3-D+Expression+Grid+Data)) in [XTK](https://github.com/xtk/X#readme)? What format should I use?

Answer (score 0):

MHD format is not natively supported yet, but you can convert the MHD to NRRD or NII using tools such as Slicer4.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Slicer4. However, I did not manage to export to a format XTK could process. https://gist.github.com/renaud/5967402 Using the demo download from Slicer4 (Download MRHead), and then save it as VTK, NII, ...

Comment: Yes that's strange there is something funny about those. Does it return any error or display something wrong?

Comment: No, the display is just blank. I think the export I did does not have the right format (ints, instead of floats, or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [c3d](http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Convert3D.Documentation) for volume format conversion.  It supports NRRD files, which I believe XTK can read.

Aside: the Allen Mouse Brain Connectivity Atlas data volumes are served as NRRD files directly.  The adult mouse gene expression atlas data volumes are still MHDs, though.